# Library creation: standard solution?

Tags: c, architecture, standards

I was wondering if there is a standard way to approach the kind of problem I'm facing:

I'm writing a library in C. The lib will provide different kind of functions, such as functions to fill arrays with particular types of data or making computation with those data.

The lib should help through the resolution of a particular problem, so one may expect that the data created at the beginning will be used to make computations later.

Thus, there are some data that should be "shared" across the problem resolution process (like the size of the arrays or some other parameters useful for computation).
I would like to avoid to put those data as parameters of every function (i.e. pass the size of an array to every function).

My idea is:

- create a set of static global variables accessible only from the library functions.
- create a setter/getter for those variables, defining a custom `enum` type that will be used to address the exact variable to set/get (i.e., `set(kScaleFactor, 10)`).

As I said before, however, is there a "standard" (or commonly used) way to address this problem? May my approach be considered ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of libraries use the concept of a 'handle' per each 'instance' of the problem. This way, you can have multiple handles open at the same time, and not messing with each others' execution, even if the calls are interspersed.

Examples: C's standard input-output has a `FILE` handle, libcURL has a `CURL` handle.

The program flow when using them usually goes in this way [I'm using an imaginary library `foo`]:

1. `FOO handle = foo_init (...);` - You obtain a `handle` that is specific to your problem. `FOO` is usually a pointer to an opaque structure that contains *all* information specific to the particular 'instance' of the problem you want to solve. All *other* functions provided by the library take a `FOO handle` parameter, so they know which instance of the problem they are working on. If `init` fails, you get a `NULL`.
2. `errorcode = foo_set_option (handle, OPTION,...);` - You then set some special options about how the library should behave when solving the problem. This may be optional. Internally, this might change the struct pointed to by `handle` to set the options.
3. `errorcode = foo_execute (handle);` - You execute a solution.
4. You might want to 'read' the solution by calling another library function. Again, `handle` is a parameter.
5. `foo_cleanup (handle);` - When you are done, you let the library clean up any internal data structures it allocated, and free any other resources it occupied.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach to library design is to design a bunch of data structures and implement operations on them. If your library works on, say, matrices, you define

```
typedef struct {
    double *contents;
    size_t ncolumns, nrows;
} Matrix;
```

and then you add a bunch of useful functions on this type (only prototypes shown):

```
Matrix *make_matrix(size_t, size_t);
Matrix *matrix_multiply(Matrix const *, Matrix const *);
```

See Pike's [Notes on Programming in C](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/pikestyle.html), rule 5 of Complexity: *data dominates*.

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate an object oriented approach. The X11 library does this by using `typedefs` to `void *` pointers. Then have functions that take the object as the first parameter and then cast it to the libraries internal data structure and use that.

I feel that using `static` will be very limiting.

*This is just my opinion*